# Who to email for interview follow up?

Tags: interviewing, internship, careers, follow-up

I interviewed 2 days ago for an internship at a defense company. The interview was with the hiring manager who also manages the team I would be working with if I got the internship. I know it's usually a good idea to send a thank you email after an interview, but unfortunately I do not have the hiring managers email. I have the HR rep's email who set up the interview and I did interact with him during the interview (he walked me in and I followed up with him after the interview). I also cannot find the hiring manager's email online (maybe it's not easily searchable because it is a defense company). Should I send a thank you email to the HR person? Or ask for the hiring manager's email from him? Or not send an email at all. They said they will be sending out a decision next week.

Comment: If the HR person has an email like firstname.lastname@company.com you could try putting in the hiring manager's name instead (not always 100% effective). You could also google the manager and look for a work email via something like LinkedIn.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I properly follow-up with a hiring manager, to check on the status of a position?](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/6018/how-do-i-properly-follow-up-with-a-hiring-manager-to-check-on-the-status-of-a-p)

Comment: @Lilienthal...this isn't a duplicate of that question, I was asking about thank you emails...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is always a good idea to send a thank you email.  I would send one to the HR rep thanking them for the assistance they provided.   Also include that you would like to email the hiring manager and ask if they can provide the email or if instead, you can send a email to them to forward.  There may be a reason you cannot find the hiring managers email online for privacy reasons and this would still get your message to them.

In your thank you make sure mention what you found intriguing about the position, and if possible a follow up question.

Good luck!